# TextBox.SelStart gives different value for mouse and keyboard

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a `TextBox` on a `Form`. I take the *cursor position* using `.SelStart` property in that `TextBox`. It works as required when I **click** within `TextBox`. I then use that position to insert certain symbols on *cursor position* by pressing *buttons* on the same form which print their *captions*.

However, if I **type** some characters with the keyboard in `TextBox`, the `Selstart` returns 0. Even though I type several characters and *cursor* visibly is at the end of text, `SelStart` remains 0. Now, if I print *buttons* on other *form* the new characters get printed always at the start of `TextBox` which is not what I want. I want the *captions* to be printed always at *cursor* location even when I type with *keyboard*.

This behavior is very puzzling. Can someone help out on this?

```
Private LastPosition as Long  'declared in form module


Private sub t_LostFocus()     'to obtain last position in `TextBox`
    LastPosition = Me!t.SelStart
End Sub


Private Sub Insert()

Dim Text As String

   If LastPosition = 0 AND IsNull(Me!t.value) Then
      Me!t.Value = " " + Me.ActiveControl.Caption
      LastPosition = LastPosition + Len(Me.ActiveControl.Caption) + 1

   ElseIf LastPosition >=0 AND Not IsNull(Me!t.Value) Then
      Text = Me!t.Value
      Me!t.Value = Left(Text, LastPosition) & " " & Me.ActiveControl.Caption & Mid (Text, LastPosition + 1)
      LastPosition = LastPosition + Len(Me.ActiveControl.Caption)+1

   Else
      Me!t.Value = Me!t.Value + " " + Me.ActiveControl.Caption

   End If

End Sub

Private Sub button1_Click()
   Call Insert
End Sub
```

Comment: could not reproduce the problem, `Selstart` always referring correct  position even if cursor is moved with mouse or typing with keyboard, or even focus shifted to other form. could insert text at desired place with `seltext  also. Or I may be failed to understand the problem clearly. may share some codes to reproduce the problem and to understand the problem correctly

Comment: I have updated question along with the code that I am using at present. `SelStart` retains the position only if I use mouse but the moment I touch keyboard it turns 0.

Comment: @AhmedAU did you take a look at the code above? I really need help on this.

Comment: There are too many gaps to adequately reproduce the behavior.  For instance, the given code does not indicate from where the sub `Insert()` is called.  You also do not describe how the **focus** is changed.  If using the mouse, does it mean that focus was changed also using the mouse (e.g. click on other control)?  Or if using the keyboard to change the cursor, is the keyboard also used to change the focus (e.g. with tab key, or ctrl+tab)?  Such details could be more important than how you are positioning the cursor while editing the TextBox.

Comment: Also, what does "print buttons on other form" mean?  From the context, I take "print" to really mean "insert button caption text into TextBox", but I'm not certain because "print" is not a very precise word to use here.  Are there multiple forms involved?

Comment: @Lone, Sorry for inconvenience caused as i overlooked tag of question. May be this [Link](https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=199910). would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a few facts about data entry on an Access Form.  These need to be understood separately to properly explain the behavior described in the question, and especially if one is trying to alter the default behavior of the control.

- The `TextBox.SelStart`, `SelLength`, and `SelText` are only available and valid when the control has focus.  When a TextBox control receives focus again, the default is for all text to be selected, so that `SelStart` = 0 and `SelLength` = length of `Text` property.  When using the mouse and clicking on the TextBox at a particular character position, the default behavior is bypassed and the cursor is placed at the mouse cursor, as expected.
- TextBox controls have both a `Text` property and a `Value` property.  The `Text` property represents the text string as it is displayed in the control.  The displayed text can be different than the underlying value that the control represents, especially if `Value` is a non-text data type (e.g. an integer is stored as a number, but represented as individual text digits).  The `Value` property returns a VBA variant which itself holds the underlying value of a *particular* data type.

  - For a bound control (i.e. the `ControlSource` property is populated), the `Value` data type will be the same as the bound source column.
  - For an unbound control (i.e. `ControlSource` is blank), the `Value` data type is dictated by the `TextBox.Format` property.  If `Format` is blank, then the data type is text and will effectively match the `Text` property.
  - `Text` and `Value` are not always synced and this is especially true when the control has focus and is being edited.  When the text is edited by the form user (i.e. not from code), `Value` is not updated until the control loses focus or *Shift+Enter* saves the form (except in cases when the Enter key behavior has been altered).  Most events that will update the control will also involve clicking or otherwise *moving focus outside the control*, like saving the record, changing focus to another control, etc.

    - When the control’s `Value` is updated, the displayed text--accessible via the `Text` property--is interpreted and/or convert into the appropriate data type which is then saved to the `Value` property.  (Sometimes the synchronization continues by reformatting the ‘Value’ back into a representation specified in the `Format` property.  For instance, if `Format = Long Date` then:  Text entered as “4-12-19” --> updated Value:  #4/12/19 00:00# → updated Text:  “Friday, April 12, 2019”.

One important last fact before I get to the point:

- **When `TextBox.Value` property is updated**--even if it is also a String data type--the `Text` property is also refreshed and the **cursor position and text selection is reset** so that the entire text is selected.  In other words, `SelStart` is set to 0 and `SelLength` is set to the length of `Text`, just like the behavior observed when the TextBox newly receives focus (as mentioned in the first point above).

*Finally to the crux of all this detail*:

- When the keyboard is used to alter the text, this will eventually trigger an update, but usually not until the control loses focus.  But when such an update occurs, it happens *before the LostFocus event* and the text selection is reset as described above, so that within the `LostFocus` event handler, `SelStart` == 0.
- **The issue is really not between keyboard and mouse, rather between the control text being altered or unaltered.**  If one only uses the arrow keys while in the textbox, then the cursor position and text selection are retained in the LostFocus event because a control update has not occurred.  Contrariwise, if the mouse is used to alter the text (e.g. right-click Paste), this also triggers an update which will reset the selection.  In fact, if one changes the text in any way and then uses the arrow keys or the mouse clicks, an update will still occur and reset the cursor position and text selection.

  - If the focus is moved outside the textbox and then back in using the mouse, an update may have occurred but the mouse will subsequently set the cursor position.  I only mention this to be aware of stray clicks that might unknowing cause an update and still give the illusion that there is unique behavior to the mouse.
- For kicks, press *Shift+Enter* to force an update but retain focus on the control, and observe that all of the text is automatically selected.

It is worth tracing the code by placing some "logging" statements in the various events, so that you can observe when they happen and the order.

---

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Database

Dim LastSelStart As Integer
Dim LastSelLength As Integer
Dim UpdateSelStart As Integer
Dim UpdateSelLength As Integer

Private Sub button1_Click()
    Insert
End Sub

Private Sub button2_Click()
    Insert
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    LastSelStart = -1
    LastSelLength = 0
    ResetUpdateSelValues
End Sub

Private Sub ResetUpdateSelValues()
    UpdateSelStart = -1
    UpdateSelLength = 0
End Sub

Private Sub t_AfterUpdate()
    On Error Resume Next
    UpdateSelStart = Me.t.SelStart
    UpdateSelLength = Me.t.SelLength
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        UpdateSelStart = -1
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub t_GotFocus()
    On Error Resume Next
    If LastSelStart >= 0 Then
        Me.t.SelStart = LastSelStart
        Me.t.SelLength = LastSelLength
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub t_LostFocus()
    LastSelStart = Me.t.SelStart
    LastSelLength = Me.t.SelLength

    If LastSelStart = 0 And UpdateSelStart > 0 Then
        LastSelStart = UpdateSelStart
        LastSelLength = UpdateSelLength
    End If

    ResetUpdateSelValues
End Sub

Private Sub Insert()
    Dim caption As String
    caption = Me.ActiveControl.caption

    If IsNull(Me.t.Value) Then
        Me.t.Value = caption
        LastSelStart = Len(caption)
        LastSelLength = 0
    Else
        Dim Text As String
        Text = Me.t.Value

        If LastSelStart = 0 Then
            '* Don't add extra space at beginning
            Text = caption & Mid(Text, LastSelLength + 1)
            'Text = caption & Text
            LastSelStart = Len(caption)
            LastSelLength = 0
        ElseIf LastSelStart > 0 Then
            Text = Left(Text, LastSelStart) & " " & caption & Mid(Text, LastSelStart + LastSelLength + 1)
            'Text = Left(Text, LastSelStart) & " " & caption & Mid(Text, LastSelStart + 0 + 1)
            LastSelStart = LastSelStart + 1 + Len(caption)
            LastSelLength = 0
        Else
            'If last cursor position is invalid, append characters
            Text = Text & " " & caption
            LastSelStart = Len(Text)
            LastSelLength = 0
        End If

        t.Value = Text
    End If

    Me.t.SetFocus
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the detailed input. I am actually a beginner in Access but I committed to develop an app that my users expect to be of a standard professional quality. So, I am still desperately looking for a solution to this issue since my users will be really irked when they observe the typed information is being misplaced rather than at the location where the cursor apparently looks to be.

Comment: @Lone  Try that code on for size.  It worked we for me with minimal testing.